# xcode 5.1.1 simulator shows smaller screen

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I just updated to xcode 5.1.1 and my app that used to run full screen, now does this!
Notice that the status bar goes down as well

Any idea??

[image: simulator small screen]

Comment: This behavior is seen when you are missing the `Default-568h@2x.png` file in your project.

Comment: This question has already been asked. You can find the answer in the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12594174/1979669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @rckoenes pointed out

This behavior is seen when you are missing the Default-568h@2x.png file in your project

So just adding it solved the problem,

@joezeitouny thank you so much for pointing me to the other thread, I already searched for it but couldn't find anything related,

Thanks!