# Why doesn't the xcode simulator show full screen

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded my xcode to version 12.3 and now when I create a new project, the simulator does not show full screen. The old projects however, does show simulator in full screen.

I checked [this (very old) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272052/xcode-5-1-1-simulator-shows-smaller-screen) and it says to add a certain file, how can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` (or .xib). When you hit Cmd-N one of the options in that dialog will allow you to add such a file.

Comment: I add that too but still didn't work full screen on simulator. Thanks

Comment: Did you set (auto layout) constraints on the green view? If so, can you update your question and show them?

Answer (score 1):

[image: open the project in Xcode -> select Target -> General -> add Launch screen in Launch Screen File]

```
open the project in Xcode -> select Target -> General -> add Launch screen in Launch Screen File
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **Info.plist** file add key: `Launch screen interface file base name` and value: `LaunchScreen`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I removed launchScreen, and then added it back

So, to add launch screen if u accidentally removed it,

> Press cmd + n

This is allow you to add new launch screen

Then in the general tab under

> App Icons and Launch Images

> Set your launch screen file

also in the deployment Info
set

> Main interface